# Keep Getting HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error After Upgrading To Latest Chrome When Trying To Generate PDF File?

Tags: apache, google-chrome, nginx, http-headers

I just recently upgraded to the latest version of Google Chrome.  However, now in the back-end of my website when I try to generate a PDF shipping label the PDF no longer generates anymore and I can see the following error in the HTTP header.

```
GET /admin/labels/print_label/374/1521 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.domain.com:443
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: jqCookieJar_options=%7B%7D; SWIFT_sessionid20=kaaczgux0pty9gww3r29zgyp36z75h0h; IEMSESSIONID=u8oogka97lvde66lh921j0hlf0; domain=ubv4uso03lvqrrsuevtf29og17; _ga=GA1.2.1572905193.1429311765; mp_ad1c0205912acf74d689fde511deecde_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2214cc99eb8c01c9-055be5978-6115117e-1fa400-14cc99eb8c1aa1%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; __qca=P0-1657043451-1429311764685; __atuvc=1%7C15; SWIFT_client=a%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A15%3A%22templategroupid%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3B%7D; SWIFT_sessionid80=cptk598artemf9d7lq0e69i5vuer89n3; SWIFT_visitor=a%3A16%3A%7Bi%3A3%3Bs%3A25%3A%22Verizon+Internet+Services%22%3Bi%3A4%3Bs%3A25%3A%22Verizon+Internet+Services%22%3Bi%3A5%3Bs%3A2%3A%22US%22%3Bi%3A12%3Bs%3A13%3A%22United+States%22%3Bi%3A6%3Bs%3A10%3A%22New+Jersey%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A10%3A%22Rutherford%22%3Bi%3A7%3Bs%3A5%3A%2207070%22%3Bi%3A8%3Bs%3A7%3A%2240.8259%22%3Bi%3A9%3Bs%3A8%3A%22-74.1079%22%3Bi%3A10%3Bs%3A3%3A%22501%22%3Bi%3A11%3Bs%3A3%3A%22201%22%3Bi%3A13%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22geoip%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A9%3A%22notecheck%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22sessionid%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22cptk598artemf9d7lq0e69i5vuer89n3%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22lastvisit%22%3Bi%3A1429311761%3B%7D; SWIFT_visitorsession=a%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A8%3A%22isbanned%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%220%22%3B%7D; _we_wk_ss_lsf_=true; __ar_v4=%7CSKM67JFKDJGIHIOPHB2Z4S%3A20150417%3A1%7CRMV2L7CXMJDO5BXHX7ARMQ%3A20150417%3A1%7CBKU6JQYLSZH7JNMGRWHTWU%3A20150417%3A1
Referer: https://www.domain.com/admin/labels/batch_shipments/batch:374/page:DHL
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="labels.pdf"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 5173
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Sat, 18 Apr 2015 02:45:27 GMT
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Pragma: public
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
```

Does anyone know why I'm receiving this error after upgrading Google Chrome to the latest version?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tested this in another browser? Have you checked your server logs for the actual error?

Comment: @lecstor actually I just tested this in other browsers (firefox, ie 11) and the same issue happens.  I guess it didn't do this in Chrome in the older version but now it seems to have the same issue just like the rest of the browsers.  Ok, I'll check the server logs to see if I can find anything.  Is there anything else I should be looking at? Thx.

Comment: no, as long as the cause of the server error has been logged, that'll tell you what the problem is.